# Calculating the time since binary output=1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, binary-data

I have a df with 2 columns: a `Binary Output` column and a column with the corresponding time. I would like to make a third column where I calculate the time since the binary output was equal to `1`. I gave a simplified example of the kind of data I'm looking at the my desired output.

I'm looking to produce the third column here:

```
Binary Output   Time (secs)   time since output=1
0               0             0
0               0.000983      0.000983
0               0.001966      0.001966
1               0.002949      0
0               0.003932      0.000983  # (0.003932-0.002949)
0               0.005000      0.002051  # (0.005000-0.002949)
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` on `BinaryOutput` to make a group for each group of zeros starting with a one, and then use `transform('first')` to get the first value for each group, and then subtract the `Time` column from the result:

```
df['time since output=1'] = df['Time (secs)'] - df.groupby(df['Binary Output'].cumsum())['Time (secs)'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Binary Output  Time (secs)  time since output=1
0              0     0.000000             0.000000
1              0     0.000983             0.000983
2              0     0.001966             0.001966
3              1     0.002949             0.000000
4              0     0.003932             0.000983
5              0     0.005000             0.002051
```