# Using R to Calculate the time since binary output=1

Tags: r, dplyr, binary, data.table, duration

I have binary data in a dataframe with a time feature and I'm looking to produce a dataframe like below with a new column "duration since =1".  I was able to find the python equivalent of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71565502/calculating-the-time-since-binary-output-1?newreg=cbda04c3e6ff4906bb91658b16c07ae5). I am looking for a way to do this in R

```
Binary Output   Time (secs)   duration since =1
0               0             0
0               0.000983      0.000983
0               0.001966      0.001966
1               0.002949      0
0               0.003932      0.000983  # (0.003932-0.002949)
0               0.005000      0.002051  # (0.005000-0.002949)
```

Comment: How are you determining `duration since =1` for the first three rows? Do you instead mean "duration since `Time[1]` or the `first(Time[Binary==1])` or the most recent `Time[Binary==1]`"? (The code there is not intended to be used, just demonstrative.)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cumsum` to indicate whether we should subtract `Time` with `Binary_Output` == 1. If `cumsum` == 0, it means all previous `Binary_Output` has a value of 0, and we will not subtract `Time` with `Binary_Output` == 1 in these rows.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Binary_Output   Time
0               0
0               0.000983
0               0.001966
1               0.002949
0               0.003932
0               0.005000")

df %>% 
  mutate(duration = ifelse(cumsum(Binary_Output) == 0, Time, Time - Time[Binary_Output == 1]))

#>   Binary_Output     Time duration
#> 1             0 0.000000 0.000000
#> 2             0 0.000983 0.000983
#> 3             0 0.001966 0.001966
#> 4             1 0.002949 0.000000
#> 5             0 0.003932 0.000983
#> 6             0 0.005000 0.002051
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,DurationSince1:=Time-nafill(fifelse(Binary_Output==1,Time,NA),type = 'locf')][]

   Binary_Output     Time DurationSince1
           <int>    <num>          <num>
1:             0 0.000000             NA
2:             0 0.000983             NA
3:             0 0.001966             NA
4:             1 0.002949       0.000000
5:             0 0.003932       0.000983
6:             0 0.005000       0.002051
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this can be solved by grouping on `cumsum(Binary_Output)` which has the benefit to reproduce OP's expected result for the first group, i.e., the first 3 rows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, duration_since_1 := Time - first(Time), by = cumsum(Binary_Output)][]
```

> ```
>    Binary_Output     Time duration_since_1
> 1:             0 0.000000         0.000000
> 2:             0 0.000983         0.000983
> 3:             0 0.001966         0.001966
> 4:             1 0.002949         0.000000
> 5:             0 0.003932         0.000983
> 6:             0 0.005000         0.002051
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("Binary_Output   Time   duration_since_1
0               0             0
0               0.000983      0.000983
0               0.001966      0.001966
1               0.002949      0
0               0.003932      0.000983
0               0.005000      0.002051")
```